# Move the remove tag "X" icon inside the tag in interesting/ignored tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, user-interface

Currently, the list of tags in "ignored tags" and "interesting tags" has a little "remove tag" icon to the right of each tag. However, since this icon is not inside the div containing the tag, it can sometimes get wrapped onto the next line, which causes confusion as to which tag will actually be removed by the "×" icon.

## Example

[image: Old Tags]

The following questions are raised:

- Which "×" do I click if I want to remove the ".net" tag?
- Which tag will be removed by clicking the "×" between "sofaq" and "not-programming-related"?

I think you could solve this by putting the "×" in the same div as the tag, as suggested by [Michael Pryor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/245/michael-pryor):

[image: new tags]

*Migrating this from [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20090827205554/http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com:80/pages/1722-general/suggestions/138951-move-the-remove-tag-icon-inside-the-tag)*

Comment: yo can we see a status-planned on this one?

Comment: p.s. this is in the top 10 highest voted feature-requests that aren't status-declined or status-completed. come on, it's low hanging fruit

Comment: @qntmfred: i added a bounty, maybe this will get some attention again. surely some of those millions of VC dollars could go to a half-hour of fixing this issue...

Comment: We're moving "X" inside of the tags, for the Favorite and Ignored sections in the sidebar. You will see the changes in the next deployment. This applies to all SE sites.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

Comment: exactly what i meant!

Comment: will this feature-request happen? with the combination of wrapping, the accidental clicking and the which X goes with which tag, this area is just begging for some TLC

Comment: That makes so much sense and is so much nicer-looking that I don't see why Jeff has decided to not even consider it. Are the Xes on your windows separate?

Comment: Can we get this fixed yet? This is ugly and a little confusing: http://i.imgur.com/4xhTp.png

Comment: @Michael your suggestion has been implemented, on all SE sites.

Comment: @jin Yay! Only took us 2 years :)

Comment: @Jin can you please elaborate about the change? I also noticed the black box does not open anymore. :)

Answer (score 29):

At least add a confirmation to that thing. I click it by accident way to often.

Comment: This is particularly an issue on mobile devices.

Answer (score 9):

Do this.  I can't figure out which X goes with which tag.

Answer (score 6):

At minimum I think there should be an `&nbsp`; between the tag and the 'x' so the 'x' doesn't get pushed over to the next line all by itself.

Comment: I do not think that this solves any problem, because _inserting_ an `&nbsp;` does not prevent the line break.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the userscript, that could wrap delete button like following

[image: before]

To

[image: after]

and also added confirmation box on delete.

[image: delete?]

[Install](http://userscripts.org/scripts/source/99876.user.js) - [Source](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/99876)

- tested only on Firefox 4, Chrome 11 Dev (Ubuntu versions)
- only @included **http://*stackoverflow.com/***

Comment: Please post userscripts on StackApps:  http://stackapps.com/questions/ask?tags=script (:

Comment: @Rebecca Chernoff, above script does not work with other stack exchange sites yet because of css I used at the moment. I will post on stackapps once I got idea how to do it on other stack exchange sites.