# Sort interested/ignored tags alphabetically

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching

The list of interesting tags would be more usable if it was ordered alphabetically.

*Apologies if this suggestion has already been made, I couldn't find it ([this is the closest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1975/ability-to-sort-reorder-interesting-ignored-tags-in-sidebar), but not quite the same).*

Comment: **YES YES YES** !! Any hope we'll see this feature sometime soon, SO team ???

Answer (score 10):

**Alphabetical sorting should be the default,** because it makes it easy to find the tags you're looking for.

As Adam suggests, there could be a switch to disable the automatic sorting, and possibly even a method to easily re-order the list and save that custom order.

Adam's manual sort sounds like a really, really ugly work-around, but one that works well. Still, it can't be the intended use -- if there's a new tag created which is very interesting to me, I would have to delete every single tag and re-add them all again, manually. Surely a more elegant solution can be provided.

Comment: I suspect that currently they are unsorted, and the query outputs them in their insertion order. In other words, I cannot believe that they are sorted by insertion time as a feature. I just can't.

Answer (score 9):

If this is implemented, it should be an optional feature, not automatic.  I have my interesting tags sorted in more-or-less the order I want them, more interesting first, even though I had to delete and re-add tags to get it that way.

Comment: Optional features are always good

Comment: Fair enough.  My interesting tags are a mess because I've been accidentally deleting them and then re-adding them due to this other problem (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23491/specify-height-width-for-remove-this-tag-image).

Comment: What do you get from having them ordered how you like them? They won't get highlighted stronger than other tags, will they?

Comment: It just makes it easier to find my 5-6 favorites among the interesting tags, having them up front.   The listing isn't very kind to the eyes if you have a lot of tags in there, it can be easy to miss things in the visual noise.

Comment: Oh, I see. The way I use those tags is just for highlighting. I.e. I add a tag and then forget about it. If I understand correcty, you frequently click on those tags to show questions using them. In that case I support your proposal.