# Is it possible to re-arrange my tags?

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Ability to sort/reorder interesting/ignored tags in sidebar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1975/ability-to-sort-reorder-interesting-ignored-tags-in-sidebar)
>   [Sort interested/ignored tags alphabetically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23488/sort-interested-ignored-tags-alphabetically)

If you look at https://stackoverflow.com/users/231181?tab=preferences#sort-top you will see my interesting tags.

You notice that I started with `Delphi-2010` and sometime later on decided to add `Delphi` too.

If I now should add `Delphi-2009` it would appear at the end. Although in practice I would like to select them the most (even `Delphi` and `Delphi-2009` and `Delphi-2010`, but that's another topic, I know).

Is it possible somehow to **sort those tags**. Or even better, **re-arrange those tags** so that I can put the most interesting ones at the top?

UPDATE: *I did search for an aleady existing question regarding this subject, but found none (I clearly used the wrong search words).*

However, having read those others, I have a suggestion for the developers: clearly you are now keeping a list of selected tags in a table. If you **add one integer field** to this table, and give us a **'upvote' link** (like you have now in front of a comment), we could very easily alter the order of tags (if you would show them according to this new field).

> Thanks for the wonderful product,
>   though. It really is appreciated by
>   other developers like myself.

Comment: That link is specific to you only.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23488/sort-interested-ignored-tags-alphabetically

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1975/ability-to-sort-reorder-interesting-ignored-tags-in-sidebar

Comment: It isn't important, but even ♦ can't see that particular page. Curious.

Comment: @Edelcom: Just to let you know... you can link your meta and so accounts (user page => accounts tab). This will give you 100 extra rep on both sites ;-)

Comment: Also: as this will probably be closed soon... you can add your feature request as an answer to the other question (possible duplicate).