# Change ordering of Interesting Tags

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching, sorting

I just accidently deleted an Interesting Tag when trying to click on the Tag.  I then readded it, but it put it at the end of the list.  Since I click on it a lot to bring up questions in that tag, it's now a tad inconvenient.

Could we be given the ability to order our Interesting Tags?

Another alternative would be an undo button for Interesting Tag deletion.

Comment: Sorting was requested [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61693/is-there-a-way-to-rearrange-the-interesting-tags-order) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35251/is-it-possible-to-re-arrange-my-tags), and undo was requested [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29584/can-we-get-a-little-doohickey-to-undelete-a-tag-from-interesting-tags). The first sorting one also links some other proposals for this issue.

Comment: @Grace, thanks I tracked it back to the true original (and the one with the most votes), and voted to close as dupe.  I wish they'd make the title search/suggestion stuff better.