# Is there a way to rearrange the interesting Tags order?

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ability to sort/reorder interesting/ignored tags in sidebar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1975/ability-to-sort-reorder-interesting-ignored-tags-in-sidebar)

I have about 20 or so 'Interesting Tags'.  I was surfing SO with my Android phone when I accidentally select the X instead of the actual tag.  I added the Tag back to my interesting tags, but now its at the bottom of the list.  Is there a way to reorder them without deleting them all and re-adding them?

Comment: Only the way you already discovered: by deleting. They are arranged by order of addition to list.

Comment: [There is no current method available outside of remove/re-add](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35251/is-it-possible-to-re-arrange-my-tags). However, there are [suggestions regarding](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1975/ability-to-sort-reorder-interesting-ignored-tags-in-sidebar) [that functionality](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23488/sort-interested-ignored-tags-alphabetically).

Comment: Yeah, I guess the feature didnt really take into account the mobile phone.  With small tags (ex: C), its easy to hit the X instead of the tag.  I know I've heard that SO wont be doing any mobile apps, maybe that would eliminate my problem.  Either that or I need to stop fat fingering everything...

Comment: There's also a few [different](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1125/move-the-remove-tag-icon-inside-the-tag) [requests](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29350/option-to-lock-interesting-tags-section-so-x-isnt-hit-accidentally-on-a-tag) for making it less easy to lose your interesting tags, consider upvoting them if you like them. Check out the [tag on the subject](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interesting-tags) to see any additional requests/reports I may have missed.