# Why did the ordering of "favourite tags" suddenly become alphabetical?

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-watching

I noticed this just today, and it's quite annoying. My hand's muscle memory automatically moves the mouse to a particular tag that I frequent (which used to be at the top), but it now lands on something else...

Was this change planned? Is this going to be accompanied with the ability to re-order/move around favourites?

Comment: Ugh. I had [c#], [mvvm], [wpf] and [xaml] together — now they're all over the place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>I changed the backend storage for tags, it used to be stored in a blob and now is stored in a table.</strike>

The new table does not maintain ordering in any way.

I can add back this functionality if it is considered critical.

Scratch that, I have a fix in the pipeline for this. Will be deployed today.

Comment: well, it's not _critical_ for me, but I've gotten used to having them at a certain position on the page for a while that it's confusing. Granted it only takes a few days to get used to, but as BoltClock mentioned above, some people might have ordered it logically for other reasons...

Comment: It would be even nicer if favorite tags could be reordered explicitly.

Comment: @starblue Post that as a feature request and I'll upvote it 100 times (once with each shiny sock-pupet)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1975/ability-to-sort-reorder-interesting-ignored-tags-in-sidebar