# Adding new tags get added to the latest tag

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

Besides the fact that the [ordering of tags changed to alphabetical order](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95341/why-did-the-ordering-of-favourite-tags-suddenly-become-alphabetical), now when adding new tags, they get added to the latest tag.

Example: I added the tag `antlr` to my favorite tags twice where `treetop` was my last one in the list:

[image]

Comment: Well, I just tried it again, and now everything works as it's supposed to. Should I remove this (bug) report?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bad ... should be deployed shortly.