# 'X' next to tag wraps when tag doesn't wrap in interesting tags list

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-watching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Move the “remove tag” icon inside the tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1125/move-the-remove-tag-icon-inside-the-tag)

In my list of interesting tags, the 'X' button is sometimes wrapped without its associated tag also being wrapped:

[SO icon http://img8.imageshack.us/img8/1899/tagwrap.png](http://img8.imageshack.us/img8/1899/tagwrap.png)

This happens in Firefox 3.5.3, but it doesn't seem to happen in IE 8.

Comment: There is a duplicate somewhere, about changing the buttons to have the X inside.

Comment: This one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1125/move-the-remove-tag-icon-inside-the-tag

Comment: I prefer the 'x' stay outside the button, and just wrap them together in a span that's styled to not break.

Comment: That was a cleverly hidden duplicate.