# Don't linewrap "remove this tag" symbol in favourites sidebar

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, tag-watching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Move the remove tag “X” icon inside the tag in interesting/ignored tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1125/move-the-remove-tag-x-icon-inside-the-tag-in-interesting-ignored-tags)

The `x` in a circle that allows you to remove a tag from your favourite tag list, it shouldn't linewrap:
[image]

This is on Chrome 10.0.648.127 on Ubuntu 10.10.

(Oh, and the `Add` buttons are actually legitimately missing their right borders, that's not an artifact of the screenshot.)

Comment: This appears to be working fine (no line wrap and the add buttons have their right border) under IE8 on Windows 7.  I've experienced the line wrap issue before on Chrome though.

Comment: It happens for me on Firefox 3.6.13 if I zoom in a couple of times too. Not like crazy zoomed in, just two steps.

Comment: See [this request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1125), which this is a duplicate of per [this bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23006). There's also [this bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56476) for the Add button issue.

Comment: @Tim Stone: Thanks for the links. I've voted to close. (why aren't I able to outright close my own questions?)

Comment: No problem, there also happens to be a feature request for [one-click self-closing of duplicates](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64920/150235) if you're interested.