# Change X - sign in interested tag

Tags: bug, tag-watching, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Move the “remove tag” icon inside the tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1125/move-the-remove-tag-icon-inside-the-tag)

IMO it will be more elegant and useful if `x` mark will be inside blue div with tag name. (then `x` will not fall down something to line below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah didn't see, there is the same thread right here - > [Move the remove tag "X" icon inside the tag in interesting/ignored tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1125/move-the-remove-tag-icon-inside-the-tag)