# Can you remove the X's from the Favorite Tags section?

Tags: feature-request, tag-bubble, tag-watching

Now that the Favorite Tags have the bubble popup, can you please remove the obnoxious delete buttons near every tag?

I keep deleting them by accident...

[image: Bombs.]

Comment: While there's an option to add/remove the tag to/from your "Favorite" list there's no option to add/remove the tag to/from your "Ingored" list.

Comment: @ChrisF - I don't care about the Ignored Tags list - I never click on the tags there, and never miss them and delete them by accident. There's also the "prefs" tab on the user page, by the way.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about you, but mine always looked like this:

[image: Favourite tags with close button inside tags]

Which always made me wonder why this question still exists: [Move the remove tag "X" icon inside the tag in interesting/ignored tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1125/move-the-remove-tag-x-icon-inside-the-tag-in-interesting-ignored-tags)

I kid, I kid... that was my own userstyle. Similarly, one can be used to accomplish this too:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

@-moz-document 
domain("stackoverflow.com"), 
domain("stackexchange.com"), 
domain("askubuntu.com"),
domain("answer.onstartup.com") {

#interestingTags .delete-tag {
  display: none !important;
}

}
```

Remove the `#interestingTags` bit will also remove the delete button from the ignored tags area.

Comment: The [linked question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1125/move-the-remove-tag-x-icon-inside-the-tag-in-interesting-ignored-tags) is now `[status-completed]`.