# Favorite tags display change

Tags: support, design, tag-watching, homepage

I noticed a change in the display of favorite tags in SO homepage - when hovering over favorite tag it no longer opens the "more details" box like it used to, just let me remove it.

I'm totally fine with this, just want official confirmation so I can add this change [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange/59446#59446). :)

Edit:
Looks like it's related to this question: [Move the remove tag "X" icon inside the tag in interesting/ignored tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1125/move-the-remove-tag-x-icon-inside-the-tag-in-interesting-ignored-tags)

But would still like official explanation of what features have been removed and what features added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We removed the tag popup in the Favorite and Ignored sections on the sidebar for usability reasons since we moved the "X" inside of the tags. This way when you hover over tags to remove them, it's not distracting. For tags you do put in Favorite or Ignored sections, chances are you know what those tags are already, so no need for additional info.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I thought, just wanted official seal on it. :)

Comment: Commenting is awesome!